# DP в PX разница между методами

Tags: android, kotlin

В каком случае будет разница в результате вычислений?

```
fun Float.dpToPx(context: Context): Int {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, this, context.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
}
```

vs

```
fun Float.dpToPx(): Int = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

В каком случае, `Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density != context.resources.displayMetrics.density` ?

Answer (score 0):

Первый фрагмент кода точно так же перемножает `this` и `displayMetrics.density` как и второй. Но в первом используются настройки отображения конкретного приложения, а во втором системные.

Подозреваю что в случае, когда ваше приложение запускается в ином режиме, чем система, пиксели получатся на выходе разные.

Один из вариантов -- compatibility mode
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element#compat-mode

Еще на ум приходят флагманские телефоны, типа Samsung S и S Note, где экран имеет мегаразрешение и системный интерфейс для него заточен, а приложения запускаются в обычном FullHD для экономии энергии.

Все что выше написано, на практике не проверено, только подсказки.